# Writing file name dinamically through the code - C

Tags: c

I'm making a program that basically receives 2 files (a .pal and a .dic file) and outputs a file called solution file (blabla.sol). However that solution file's name depends on one of those files that the program received. How can I modify my program in order to change the output file's name depending on the name of the received file's name? In this case I want it to be the same names as my name_pal file.

Here's the program that I've already written (right now, as it is, it only outputs a file with a fixed name):

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      char name_dic[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE]; 
      char name_pal[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE]; 
      char name_sol[] = "prob0.sol"; 

      char words_dic[MAX_WORD_SIZE]; 
      char words_pal[MAX_WORD_SIZE]; 
      char word_same_size[MAX_WORD_SIZE];

      char dic_total[MAX_DIC_SIZE][MAX_WORD_SIZE]; 
      char pal_total[MAX_PAL_SIZE][MAX_WORD_SIZE];

      FILE *dic, *pal, *sol;

      if (argc < 3)
      {
          printf("Missing files.\n");
          exit(1);
      }

      strcpy(name_dic, argv[1]); 
      strcpy(name_pal, argv[2]); 

      dic = fopen(name_dic, "r"); 
      if (dic == NULL)            
      {
         printf("Can not open dictionary file: %s\n", name_dic);
         exit(1);
      }

      pal = fopen(name_pal, "r");
      if (pal == NULL)
      {
          printf("Can not open problem file: %s\n", name_pal);
          exit(1);
      }

      sol = fopen(name_sol, "w");
      if (sol == NULL)
      {
           printf("Can not open solution file: %s\n", name_sol);
           exit(1);
      }
      /* rest of the code */
```

Comment: `char name_sol[] = "prob0.sol";` Don't define it statically. Put here the logic for naming, whatever format you want it to be named!

Comment: Also you can ask the user the file name and allocate that to the char array.

Comment: Don't think about it as a filename - think about it as a string that you want to construct. How would you take one string (which happens to be the source filename) and convert it to another (which happens to be the destination filename)?  Probably by looking for the last '.' in the filename, cutting it there to remove the extension, and appending a new extension that you want. Once you have the string, you can use it as the filename.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I did it basically putting a strncpy up until a fixed number (because all the source files are the same length) and strcat to append it to my name_sol string, as @user3486184 said.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a truncate function at the '.' and then append sol as shown in snippet below.

```
      char name_sol[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];

      int i;
      for(i=0;i<MAX_FILENAME_SIZE;i++){
              name_sol[i]=name_pal[i];
              if(name_sol[i]=='.') break;
      }
      strcpy(name_sol+i+1,"sol");
      printf("%s\n",name_sol);
```